# Can globalmapper tag be changed to global-mapper?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The product name is **[Global Mapper](http://www.bluemarblegeo.com/products/global-mapper.php)** and by naming convention its tag would be [global-mapper](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/global-mapper).

However, the tag is currently named [globalmapper](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/globalmapper) so can it be changed?

Comment: I'm wondering if there will really be some benefit to doing so.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe I think it is about pride in our site - I hope visitors will think "even the tags have been thought about and named consistently".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created the [global-mapper](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/global-mapper) tag and made it the preferred synonym of [globalmapper](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/globalmapper).  This makes both forms available for search but displays the former.